# ¿Como consieguir el total de registros que tiene EPOC?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Intento sacar el total de registros de una tabla pero, como le hago para que me de el total. Adjunto imagenes para que se entienda mejor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa es la imagen de la tabla donde estan los valores la tabla tiene mas de 14,000 datos
cuando realizo esta consulta me sale este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora lo que quiero es **sacar el la suma total de la columna total (Sin la necesidad de crear otra tabla)**, pero la columna total no existe en la base de datos solo es un alias que se creo para que me mostrara el total de las filas con esos datos que se solicitan.

Comment: o sea.. vos queres la suma de lo que ya sumaste? salga el group by y la columna del select y vas a tener el total de toda la tabla...

Comment: Si, quiero la suma total de la columna "Total", pero la columna "Total" no existe ya que se creo como un alias para que me mostrara la suma de las filas que tienen los datos 1,2 y 98

Comment: La columna total existe.. solo le cambiaste el nombre a una columna que se llamaba count(idEPOC)... proba hacer eso que te dije, sin importar el nombre de las columnas (que sirve solo para mostrar) y te va a dar el resultado que queres...

Comment: Pero no entiendo bien a que te refieres con "salga el group by y la columna del select". Si me podrias explicar mejor, te lo agradeceria.

Comment: Por favor, la proxima vez el codigo como texto, si no obligas a copiar todo el codigo para el que te de la solucion. De paso mira [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Si la query

```
select idepoc, count(idepoc) as total from padecimientos group by idepoc
```

Devuelve lo que vos queres, pero agrupado por idepoc, y vos solo queres el total, entonces lo que podes hacer es solamente contar todo lo que tiene la tabla

```
select count(idepoc) from padecimientos
```

De esa forma vas a contar todo.